# How to prevent OneLogin Protect android app v4.3.0 from crashing?

Tags: android, crash, runtime-error, onelogin

> #### DISCLAIMER
>
> I'm opening this Q&A because:
>
> - I've tried contacting OneLogin [through Twitter](https://twitter.com/AndreaLigios/status/1205068733540163590) without success
> - I can't fill a bug without a Developer Account (which I don't want)
> - **They clearly state in their site to ask on Stackoverflow when seeing weird errors**:
>
>   [image]

#### THE PROBLEM

In my company, we're using the OneLogin Protect as 2FA (OTP) device for accessing a partner VPN.

On December 10, 2019, OneLogin released the version 4.3.0 of its app, which our smartphones automatically updated from the previous 4.1.0, which was fully working.

**The 4.3.0 app crashes when starting, with a miserable NPE:**

[image]

#### THE ATTEMPTS AND THE QUESTIONS

I've reinstalled it, reinstalled the previous version (which got updated again), disabled the automatic updates (which is not something I'm happy about), but this is so fragile, so I'm asking:

- **Is this happening to us only, or it's a huge production bug?**
- **Is there any way to fix it?**
- **Are you guys at OneLogin aware of this? Are you working on it? Have you a release date for a patched version?**

> Hint: the problem is in the Kotlin file Utils.kt, row 42. Sanitize the input, for God sake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug has been found and fixed and a new version has been posted to the Play Store. If you update, look for version 4.3 (187) or higher.